# how to seek position in datatable before writing to the file

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the data table that is read from csv file. Then it is iterated through row and columns, and each value is appended before writing to the file that is also destination csv file. I want to separate the data of one column upon the special character ("/"), into two columns. For example, the column of 'Type' of data table is "women/shoes and handbags/guess". I have another column 'SubType', so I want to separate one column to two columns in data table before writing. I just want to ignore third type that is guess. Is there a way to seek position "/" and after second "/", I want to insert that value into another column of data table that is 'SubType'.

```
    foreach (DataRow dRow in dtSor.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSor.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dRow[i].ToString().Contains(","))
            {
                dest_csv.Append("\"" + dRow[i].ToString() + "\"" + ",");
            }

            else if (dRow[i].ToString() == "")
            {
                dest_csv.Append("NULL" + ",");
            }

            else
            {
                dest_csv.Append(dRow[i].ToString() + ",");
                //dest_csv.Append(dRow[i].ToString());
            }

        }

        dest_csv.Remove(dest_csv.Length - 1, 1);
        dest_csv.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(destination_file, dest_csv.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
}
```

Comment: I don't entirely get what you want or don't want. What result do you expect? Type = "women" SubType = "shoes"? Is " and handbags/guess" part of the same column value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the special char is in the field with [indexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.85%29), then [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) the field on the special char in an araay and take only the parts you're intereseted in.

like so:

```
const char special = '\\';

string maintype ="";
string subtype ="";

string field = dRow[i].ToString();
if (field.IndexOf(special)>-1)
{
  string[] splitted = field.Split(special);
  maintype = splitted[0];
  subtype = splitted[1];
}
```

Comment: The destination file has extra column because 'SubType' column is blank when reading from source data table. There are other blank columns in the source data table. So when that column is checked with if condition, there is an error "== operator cannot be applied to data column and bool". How will I fix this error and make the destination file as the desired result that is the exact columns from the source data table. Thanks a lot.

Comment: else if (dtSor.Columns["SubType"] == true)
             {
                 dest_csv.Append(subtype + ",");
             }

Comment: I appreciate your solution. I got it fixed.